# How to clear the Application Output

Tags: android, windows, xamarin-studio

I've been using Xamarin Studio for a while to develop for Android but it seems that I'm absolutely unable to clear the Application Output window. Am I having a broken version without a clear button? Did I see this button on OSX and it is missing in Windows? (I've used Xamarin Studio a lot of Mac before, can't remember if this functionality exists on Mac, but intuitively seeking for this in Windows.)

What I have tried: to check carefully around the Pad for any eraser button.
What I've found: no functionality at all.

[Edit]

Version:

> Xamarin Studio
>   Version 5.9.4 (build 5)
>
> Installation UUID: 4b0c29f9-f2a9-4140-ae43-848d49cc62b7
>
> Runtime:
>     Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.34014
>     GTK+ 2.24.22 (MS-Windows theme)
>     GTK# 2.12.26
>
> Xamarin.Android
>   Version: 5.1.4 (Enterprise Edition)
>
> Version is 5.9.4 (build 5).

It looks like this:

[image]

I think I'll fill a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

[image: clear button in xamarin studio on windows]

well, I have the button at the right side of Application output.

Comment: Ohhhh. Seems like my Application Output is broken. Are you using the Mac or the Windows version?

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: Xamarin Studio on Mac

Comment: Ok. I'm experiencing it in Windows.